# Convert array keys and values to a string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I got an array

```
["id":16,"name":"Allayne","city":"Karkkila","gender":"Male","valid_to":"2019-09-25","note":"server"],
["id":17,"name":"Wilfred","city":"Tungor","gender":"Male","valid_to":"2020-01-12","note":"client"],
["id":18,"name":"Cyrille","city":"Xi’an","gender":"Male","valid_to":"2020-02-28","note":"client"],
["id":19,"name":"Janeen","city":"Sorochuco","gender":"Female","valid_to":"2020-05-22","note":"server"],
["id":20,"name":"Nelli","city":"Falun","gender":"Female","valid_to":"2020-04-02","note":"client"],
["id":21,"name":"Teressa","city":"Bobon","gender":"Female","valid_to":"2020-04-22","note":"client"],
["id":22,"name":"Birk","city":"Amu Gulang Baolige","gender":"Male","valid_to":"2019-12-10","note":"server"],
["id":23,"name":"Percival","city":"Podgortsy","gender":"Male","valid_to":"2019-12-20","note":"client"],
["id":24,"name":"Lemuel","city":"Kamionka Strumitowa","gender":"Male","valid_to":"2020-02-24","note":"client"]
```

and I wanna joint strings group by gender with php like below,

```
#1
gender：male
name：
aaa
bbb
-----------

#2
gender：female
name：
ccc
ddd
```

could show me how or teach me how to do!
thank you !

here is the play ground for this question
https://www.tehplayground.com/bHsPFyAVFZ3tjHAn

I used group_by at the first step
but I can't figure it out to put strings as the format as I want
thank you!

---

here is my original code, $data is the source array

```
function group_by($key, $data)
{
    $result = [];

    foreach ($data as $val) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $val)) {
            $result[$val[$key]][] = $val;
        } else {
            $result[""][] = $val;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$byGroup = group_by("gender", $data);

// echo "<pre>" . var_export($byGroup, true) . "</pre>"."\n";


function myPlus($users)
{
    return array_map(function($user) {
        return $user['name'];
    }, $users);
}


$a = array_map("myPlus", $byGroup);
print_r($a);
```

Comment: Use `foreach()`, test the gender and add to a new array.

Comment: I can group the array by gender, but I can't print the strings as the format I want.
(https://www.tehplayground.com/bHsPFyAVFZ3tjHAn)
it's php play ground,
could you teach me how to do the next step, thank you !

Comment: You should provide the code you use here, not in an external link that can disappear.

Comment: excuse me, I update my code here,thank you!

Comment: I dunno why the question is closed and was reopened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to keep your code for grouping:

```
function group_by($key, $data)
{
    $result = [];

    foreach ($data as $val) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $val)) {
            $result[$val[$key]][] = $val;
        } else {
            $result[""][] = $val;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$byGroup = group_by("gender", $data);
echo "#1
gender：male
name：
";
foreach ($byGroup['Male'] as $person) {
    echo $person['name'],"\n";
}
echo "-----------

#2
gender：female
name：
";
foreach ($byGroup['Female'] as $person) {
    echo $person['name'],"\n";
}
```

Else, I'd simply do:

```
foreach ($data as $person) {
    if ($person['gender']==='Male'){
        $m .= $person['name'] . "\n";
    } else {
        $f .= $person['name'] . "\n";
    }
}
echo "#1
gender：male
name：
$m
-----------

#2
gender：female
name：
$f";
```